# What is Cookie “pma_lang_https”?

Tags: php, ajax, cookies

What is this in message in console? And how to solve it now?

[image: coocie]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cookie “PHPSESSID” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against <file> because the scheme does not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63297970/cookie-phpsessid-will-be-soon-treated-as-cross-site-cookie-against-file-beca)

Comment: `pma_` sounds like a `phpMyAdmin` cookie.

Answer (score 1):

pma_lang_https cookie is phpMyAdmin database manager language. phpMyAdmin creates this cookie to store language configuration. You can delete the cookies tied to localhost to remove these messages. Removing the cookies tied to localhost may impact phpMyAdmin and other projects that uses cookies.